# Angular custom header in interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, angular-http-interceptors

I am working on an Angular 9 application with a request interceptor, which is supposed to send the server the UI version that is making the request.

Because this data is required for requests, I added it in an interceptor. The problem is that it seems that it is not working correctly.

Here is my interceptor code:

```
@Injectable()
export class VersionInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const version = request.clone({ setHeaders: { 'App-version':  environment.UIversion } });
    return next.handle(version);
  }
}
```

and this in may app.module providers

```
providers: [
    { provide: Http, useClass: AuthenticatedHttpService },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorHttpInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: VersionInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: environment.baseurl },
]
```

But my requests don't have the header "App-version"

[image]

only one request has it and it fails (But if I remove the interceptor, this request works fine)

[image]

Is there a standard to send my ui version in headers?
If not, is there any way to add a custom header name to send my ui version to the server?

Thank you very much

Comment: How does it fail? It might be a CORS issue with forbidden header

Comment: how is the request failing? (http error code)?

Comment: There's no fail in the response. I'm pretty sure that the request does not even reach the server (image 2). It must be some problem of the request, because removing that header, the request works well. The requests that reach the server, do not include that header and I do not understand why

Answer (score 0):

I found that I also couldn't pass custom headers. However, I could pass custom parameters on the call which were available in the interceptor.

**In Service pseudo code**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getMethod(): Observable<Type> {
  let params = { "X-custom-param": "true" };
  let options = { params: params };
  this.http.get<Type>(url, options);
}
```

**In Interceptor**

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return next.handle(request).pipe(
    tap((e) => {}),
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      let custom = request.params.get("X-custom-param");
```